# RethinkDB: how to use r.getPoolMaster().on('healthy' with a rethinkdb-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I'm using RethinkDB feeds with a NodeJS application in order to keep track on the changes in the database.

When RethinkDB goes down i use

```
r.getPoolMaster().on('healthy'
```

to keep track if RethinkDB is alive or not, and rejoin the feeds.

This works just fine. When RethinkDB goes down it emits a healthy event with the value of false and another one with the value of true when it goes up.

But now i need to use a RethinkDB-Proxy in front of my RethinkDB instance and i'm making my Node app connect to the Proxy. The problem is that when i use a Proxy and RethinkDB goes down, it's not emitting the healthy event or at least i don't get it bc i'm connected to the Proxy.

Is there a way to make the Proxy emit this event? Or to capture it from my instance? Or any other possible approach?

Hope i was clear enough

Thanks!